# PhoneGap 3.0.0 Tanelih Bluetooth Plugin on Android isEnabled onError callback not working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, bluetooth, phonegap-plugins

I am testing out the functions of [Tanelih's Bluetooth Plugin](https://github.com/tanelih/phonegap-bluetooth-plugin) for PhoneGap 3.0.0 on Android.
The plugin seems to be working quite well; I can turn the BlueTooth on and off using HTML buttons linked to the JavaScript functions and get the onSuccess/onError callbacks to display messages if the functions worked or not.

However, when I try and see if BlueTooth is enabled using `window.bluetooth.isEnabled(isEnabledSuccess, isEnabledError);`the callback is always isEnabledSuccess regardless of whether the BlueTooth is enabled or disabled.

Here is some of my index.html:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for device API libraries to load
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() 
{
   window.bluetooth.isEnabled(isEnabledSuccess, isEnabledError);
}

function isEnabledSuccess(isEnabled)
{
   var element = document.getElementById('status');
   element.innerHTML = "Enabled";
}

function isEnabledError(isEnabled)
{
   var element = document.getElementById('status');
   element.innerHTML = "Disabled";
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="status"></p>
</body>
```

Here's some of bluetooth.js (I have not touched this file):

```
    Bluetooth.prototype.isEnabled = function(onSuccess, onError)
    {
    exec(onSuccess, onError, "Bluetooth", "isEnabled", []);
    }
```

Here's some of BluetoothPlugin.java (I have not touched this file):

```
     /**
     * Is Bluetooth on.
     * 
     * @param args          Arguments given.
     * @param callbackCtx   Where to send results.
     */
    private void isEnabled(JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackCtx)
    {
        try 
        {
            callbackCtx.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, _bluetooth.isEnabled()));
        } 
        catch(Exception e) 
        {
            this.error(callbackCtx, e.getMessage(), BluetoothError.ERR_UNKNOWN);
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error function will only be called if a Java exception occurs during the call to the plugin (which is unlikely). The success function is returned a boolean which tells you whether Bluetooth is enable or not. So instead, try something like this:

```
function onDeviceReady() 
{
   window.bluetooth.isEnabled(isEnabledSuccess, isEnabledError);
}

function isEnabledSuccess(isEnabled)
{
   var element = document.getElementById('status');
   if(isEnabled){
     element.innerHTML = "Enabled";
   }else{
     element.innerHTML = "Disabled";
   }
}

function isEnabledError(error)
{
   var element = document.getElementById('status');
   element.innerHTML = "Cannot determine Bluetooth status: " + error.message;
}
```